# Oracle converting a function to a trigger

Tags: oracle, function, hash, raw

I have the following function,  which works,that I would like to convert into a INSERT/UPDATE
trigger for the column hash_pk.  I'm struggling with syntax errors trying to convert this to a trigger. Could someone please help me out.

Secondly, would it be more efficient to store the column hash_pk as a RAW(if so how big) instead of a VARCHAR2?

Thanks in advance to all that answer.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION HASH_SHA512 (
    psINPUT IN VARCHAR2
    ) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    rHash RAW (512);
    BEGIN
    rHash := DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH (TO_CLOB (psINPUT), 
dbms_crypto.HASH_SH512);
    RETURN ((RAWTOHEX (rHash)));
    END HASH_SHA512;
/  

CREATE table t(
seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
hash_pk VARCHAR2(1000) not NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
c CLOB,
create_date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
);
/

create or replace
    trigger hash_trg
    before insert  or update on  t
   for each row
    begin
    :new.hash_pk := HASH_SHA512(:new.c);
    end;
  

 insert into t (c) values (
      rpad('z',16,'z')
  );

SELECT * from t

SEQ_NUM    HASH_PK    C    CREATE_DATE
1    2C9437F9D8FB13FC959CA2B9D5B81958B5A32556C60E35D66D1DA92227593A14316FD32EE2B3EEE06EECB1484A0CACAE61A4F930E772BB78AC84E75948DAA628    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz    12-OCT-21


update t set c='Good Bye';

SELECT * from t;

SEQ_NUM    HASH_PK    C    CREATE_DATE
1    DCBC14FA2F46F1E264BBD52C4A3DF87E32CC511B43FD9AD722EACCFCA6D8CBE398D10E61E83A85625C7CF96E70348F2D33595196577B01C488030E560A7D34F7    Good Bye    12-OCT-21
```

Comment: whats the error  do you get on compiling trigger  ?

Comment: @Ali Fidanli thanks for responding. I got and answered my own

Answer (score 0):

I got it was missing parenthesis

```
create or replace
    trigger hash_trg
    before insert  or update on  t
   for each row
    begin
    :new.hash_pk := DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH  ((:new.c), 
dbms_crypto.HASH_SH512);
    end;
```